# Dropdown list in yii is not working

Tags: php, yii, dropdown

I have written the following code to create a dropdown list in Yii using CActiveForm but it is giving me an error "htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given".

```
echo form->dropDownList($model,'user_id',array('All'=>'All','Members'=>'Members','BusinessUsers'=>'BusinessUsers','SelectedUsers'=>'SelectedUsers'),array('htmlOptions'=>array('name'=>'dd',)));
```

Comment: are you sure that error is at this point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of you are passing HTML options of this dropdown incorrect. Instead of:

```
echo form->dropDownList($model,'user_id',array('All'=>'All','Members'=>'Members','BusinessUsers'=>'BusinessUsers','SelectedUsers'=>'SelectedUsers'),array('htmlOptions'=>array('name'=>'dd',)));
```

you need to use this:

```
echo form->dropDownList($model, 'user_id', array('All'=>'All','Members'=>'Members','BusinessUsers'=>'BusinessUsers','SelectedUsers'=>'SelectedUsers'), array('name'=>'dd'));
```

**Note:**

Why are you setting `name` property? Remember, that you are using `CActiveForm` to connect your form with `$model`. In this case Yii will generate `name` attribute accordingly to your model name and `user_id`. If you change `name`, assigning data sent by POST can be messed up!

Comment: So if this post is accepted, please accept this aswer :)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work :)